What is A320 "PC DEDICATED TO MAINTENANCE"?
What is meant by "PC DEDICATED TO MAINTENANCE" in the FCOM of A320 in cockpit preparation?
I could not understand what is meant by this item.

more context is needed.

This is very airline specific. If you are a online pilot, it doesnt apply to you. If you are about to join an airline, they will tell you. Just know it is there.

At least one airline's SOPs (although for an A340) clarify that this means:

Check that the Personal Computer (PC), dedicated to maintenance use and located in front of the 4th
occupant console, is stowed.

The A320 manual from Airbus has the following content:



Check that the Personal Computer (PC) dedicated to maintenance use and located in front of lower stowage at RH rear corner is stowed.
Check that the light of its manual switch is off. If not, switch it off.
Check that its associated printer located in front of RH rear of the cockpit is stowed.

